# Why are audits not scored?

Tags: discussion, reputation, review-audits, score

My apologies if this has been asked before. Meta's suggestions and a Google search are not returning any promising results.

Why are audits not scored? Perhaps a +3 for a successful audit and a -5 for a failed audit would be a useful tool to keep people engaged in auditing while keeping them on their toes.

I'm not suggesting to replace the current system. This is more an augmentation to encourage folks to work on various queues with a more immediate reward (when an audit is encountered).

Comment: "Your audit score is so bad (and you should feel bad) that we're just going to keep giving you audits to add insult to injury. Before banning you."

Comment: Thanks  BoltClock's a Unicorn. I was not aware my audit score was that bad. Where I can see the score and how it compares to others?

Comment: @animuson - this might be a duplicate, but the question was not really answered in the cited duplicate. I think its more correct to mark it as "previously asked", and not "already answered".

Comment: @noloader: Dupes on Meta do not require an answer, and there is no 'previously asked' close reason just for Meta.

Comment: @noloader yes it was answered, scroll down a bit and you will see answer below the comments. And the answer even got accepted.